# Retrieve Shared dataextension records

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions

how to retrieve shared data extension records through soap api marketing cloud.
i am Trying so many ways but i am not getting result can  you please give me suggestion for to achieve this problem. here i am using below code please check once and what i modifying in this code.

```
    <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Header>
 <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
 <UsernameToken>
  <Username>Kumar@gmail.com</Username> 
  <Password>Wel444</Password>  
  </UsernameToken>
  </Security>
  </Header>
 <Body>
 <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
 <RetrieveRequest>
 <ObjectType>DataExtensionobject[ENT.Acc_01]</ObjectType>
 <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
 <Properties>customId</Properties>
 <Properties>feedback</Properties>
 <QueryAllAccountsSpecified>true</QueryAllAccountsSpecified>
 </RetrieveRequest>
 </RetrieveRequestMsg>
     </Body>
  </Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with Shared Data Extensions, you need to add the ENT. prefix to the DE name. In your case, it will be ENT.Acc_01

And have you at all looked at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension.htm)? 
It mentions the object type element having this format:

```
<ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[ENT.Acc_01]</ObjectType>
```

However your code uses this format:

```
<ObjectType>DataExtensionobjectent.[Acc_01]</ObjectType>
```

Comment: Hi @Lukas L 
 I used ENT also but result getting Error.Please Check below error .

Comment: <OverallStatus>Error: DataExtensionobjectent.[ENT.Acc_messageReactions_100388201] is not a valid ObjectType.</OverallStatus>

Comment: Please see my edited answer

Comment: I used Same like u told but i am getting result error.

Comment: Please Check below error
  <OverallStatus>Error: Data extension does not exist: ENT.Acc_01</OverallStatus>

Comment: @UserSFMC well - at least you now use the correct format for object type. Have you tried to use name vs external ID of the DE? You are on the right track

Comment: I tried same as u told please  check my below code.

Comment: ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[ENT.TestDE]</ObjectType>
<QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
 <Properties>Name</Properties>
  <Properties>email</Properties>